# Bubble sort in HCS12 Assembly language

Tags: assembly, bubble-sort

HCS12 Assembly Language
trying to bubble sort the array, but turns out that it goes into infinite loop when ever i run it and only replaces the first element

```
;constants
STACK   equ     $2000

; data array
org     $1000
Array   db  $FF, $FE, $01, $05, $83, $FF, $C0, $01
        db  $83, $02, $F3, $28, $80, $01, $00, $06
Array_End

Destination_Array        ds     Destination_Array-Array    ; calculating size of array
End_Destination

org        $2000

Start   lds     #STACK                 ; stack location

    ldx     #Array
    ldy     #Destination_Array
back:

    ldaa    1,x+
    staa    1,y-
    cpx     #Array_End-1
    bne     back

next_pass:
    ldaa    #$0
    staa    Array
    ldx     #Destination_Array

next:
    ldaa    0,x
    cmpa    1,x
    blt     notnow
    ldab    1,x
    stab    0,x
    staa    1,x
    ldaa    #$01
    staa    Array

notnow:
    inx
    cpx #End_Destination
    bne next
    tst Array
    bne next_pass
    swi
```

Comment: Looks like you have your stack at the same location as your code, so any use of the stack (e.g. by interrupts) will overwrite code.  After the LDS instruction,  instruction pointer = stack pointer (well, a couple bytes below the stack pointer).  This may not be an actual problem, though, if your simulator doesn't do interrupts.

Comment: Which loop does your code get stuck in, and what values are in registers?

Comment: re: the stack.  I have that backwards, I think.  The stack grows down from there, while code is at increasing addresses.  It's just weird to see the same address being used for both, but that's what happens if the top of the stack is just below the code.  And you left plenty of room between the data and code for the stack.